# The Saga of understanding how to apply Axon

Tags: axon, saga

I was referring to the Axon documentation trying to implement a Saga:  https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/sagas/implementation

As is the case with everything else I've encountered thus far in Axon's documentation I could see no big picture, no diagrams or code examples or even any reference to example code in Github to help me get started.

I know what Saga means conceptually and what it solves. What I'm unable to understand from the documentation is how to apply that concept using Axon's artifacts. There is not one area that is written holistically and completely.

Does anyone have any good reference, books that helps me apply Axon? I'm currently evaluating Axon (and I'm not willing to buy the "support") and the quality of the documentation has almost forced me to look elsewhere (Eventuate).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [this](https://axoniq.io/blog-overview/sagas-in-practice) blog about Saga's with code samples I hope this helps you to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Next to the blog that Yvonne has shared, you could take a look at this book from Vijay Nair:

- [https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Domain-Driven-Design-Enterprise-Java/dp/1484245423](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484245423)

It explains several approaches towards building DDD applications, with the last one diving into Axon's idea of it.

Added, AxonIQ is working on a training environment:

- https://academy.axoniq.io/

So, a website with videos and written material about anything Axon-related.
The two courses that are on there right now, are free. Granted, Saga's/Process Manager aren't present there yet, although they should come soon.

When it comes to sample applications using Axon (that are maintained by  AxonIQ developers), I'd refer to these:

- https://github.com/AxonIQ/hotel-demo -> complete application touching as much of Axon's components as possible
- https://github.com/AxonIQ/code-samples -> repository containing more fine-grained samples
- https://github.com/fraktalio -> contains several sample projects, of which I'd recommend the restaurant, order, and courier demos

Apart from sharing the info, I am sad to hear you find the Reference Guide lacking at this stage. Any recommendations on improvements are from your current description, rather vague to be honest. If you have the time and interest to enhance this *open source* product, know you can always open some issue for the guide too. I am not asking you to write the documentation, but a description of the missed would be much appreciated.

- https://github.com/AxonIQ/reference-guide

Comment: Thanks, at this point Eventuate appears to be a practical and well documented alternative apart from being purely open source and comes with no "enterprise" (read 'free') tag attached. Moreover, I was able to get started with it already, whereas I wasted a week trying to figure out how to get Axon working.

Comment: Best thing is you found something that works for you, so kudos to that. Regardless, if your time allows it to pinpoint more exactly where you got stuck would be helpful for Axon Framework. It's a sentiment I haven't heard at all yet, hence a more concrete example would benefit the framework and, more importantly, others reading your question here to not step in the same predicament.